# How to launch Intellij Idea's Java tests from JMeter?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, jmeter, performance-testing, junit-jupiter

I need to find a way to launch tests from Intellij Idea in JMeter. I tried to use JUnit Request but it supports junit 3 and 4, and I use junit 5 that's why it's not possible to use this sampler. Also I tried to use Java Request and JSR223 request by trying to write code that initializes my tests and triggers their execution. I used ChatGPT help with that, but unsuccessful. Could you help me with that, please? It's been several days already and I still cannot resolve the problem.

ChatGPT examples of code:
//JSR223 Sampler

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import com.example.MyTest; // Import your test class

public class MyTestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(MyTest.class); // Replace with your test class
        System.out.println("Total tests executed: " + result.getRunCount());
        System.out.println("Total tests failed: " + result.getFailureCount());
    }
}
```

//Java Request Sampler

```
import org.example.MyTest;

public class TestRunner {
    public void runTests() {
        MyTest test = new MyTest(); // Replace with your test class
        test.setup(); // Replace with your test setup method
        test.runTests(); // Replace with your test execution method
        test.tearDown(); // Replace with your test cleanup method
    }
}
```

// In the Java Request, create an instance of TestRunner and call runTests():
new TestRunner().runTests();

---

Also I put a jar of the project in lib/ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is **really** what you're looking for (I mean it's possible to run everything from JMeter but you're unlikely to get good results), assuming that you have:

1. Your [test classes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) copied to "lib/junit" folder of your JMeter execution
2. JUnit5 and all its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) copied to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Any other 3rd-party libraries which are needed by your tests in JMeter Classpath
4. [junit-platform-launcher](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher) is in JMeter Classpath (if not yet)
5. JMeter is restarted to pick everything up

You should be able to use the following code to kick off your tests

```
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.SummaryGeneratingListener

import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectClass;

def listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener()
def request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
        .selectors(selectClass(com.example.MyTest.class))
        .build()
Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create()
launcher.discover(request)
launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener)
launcher.execute(request);
log.info('Passed: ' + listener.getSummary().getTestsSucceededCount())
log.info('Failed: ' + listener.getSummary().getTestsFailedCount())
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried your method and I add junit-jupiter,  junit-jupiter-api, junit-platform-engine, junit-platform-launcher jars to lib and I got this error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException

Maybe it's not enough jars or there is a conflict?
Can it be another reason for the error?

Comment: I think [junit-platform-commons](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-commons) is missing Here is what I have in my [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) just in case: `apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar;junit-jupiter-api-5.10.0.jar;junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.0.jar;junit-platform-commons-1.10.0.jar;junit-platform-engine-1.10.0.jar;junit-platform-launcher-1.10.0.jar;opentest4j-1.3.0.jar;`Normally [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) file should have enough troubleshooting information

Comment: I add junit-platform-commons and it helped, thanks! But unfortunately It looks like tests didn't run: 
INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler 3: Passed: 0
INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler 3: Failed: 0

Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: It's maximum I can do for you with the information you provided, if tests fail somewhere somehow check jmeter.log and stdout/stderr for any suspicious entries