# Cannot run Intellij Idea's parameterized test from jmeter

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, jmeter, performance-testing, junit-jupiter

I need to find a way to launch parameterized test from Intellij Idea in JMeter. Here ([How to launch Intellij Idea's Java tests from JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76867778/how-to-launch-intellij-ideas-java-tests-from-jmeter)) I got good help with launching the tests, but I still cannot run the test. It seems, the test's not visible for jmeter. I added junit 5 and all its dependencies jars and all dependencies I have in my project to JMETER_HOME/lib, also I add a jar containing test classes to JMETER_HOME/lib.

Here's the code I use in JSR223 Sampler:

```
import org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.SummaryGeneratingListener
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.TestExecutionSummary

import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectClass;
import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod;

import static org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.*;

def listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener()

def request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
        .selectors(
            selectClass(com.example.MyTest.class),
            selectMethod(com.example.MyTest.class, "myTest", String.class)).build()

def launcher = LauncherFactory.create()
launcher.discover(request)
launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener)
launcher.execute(request)

def summary = listener.getSummary()

log.info('Total tests executed: ' + summary.getTestsFoundCount())
log.info('Total tests succeeded: ' + summary.getTestsSucceededCount())
log.info('Total tests failed: ' + summary.getTestsFailedCount())
```

Logs I get:

```
2023-08-14 12:05:13,051 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='...\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin'
2023-08-14 12:05:13,056 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: ...\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\MyTest\Test.jmx
2023-08-14 12:05:13,056 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='...\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\MyTest'
2023-08-14 12:05:13,266 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2023-08-14 12:05:13,281 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2023-08-14 12:05:13,281 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2023-08-14 12:05:13,286 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: ...\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\MyTest\Test.jmx
2023-08-14 12:05:14,051 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2023-08-14 12:05:14,051 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to UTF-8
2023-08-14 12:05:14,051 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2023-08-14 12:05:14,051 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2023-08-14 12:05:14,537 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='...\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin\MyTest'
2023-08-14 12:05:28,217 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2023-08-14 12:05:28,222 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2023-08-14 12:05:28,222 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2023-08-14 12:05:28,222 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2023-08-14 12:05:28,222 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2023-08-14 12:05:28,527 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2023-08-14 12:05:28,527 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2023-08-14 12:05:28,527 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2023-08-14 12:05:28,527 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2023-08-14 12:05:28,532 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2023-08-14 12:05:28,542 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2023-08-14 12:05:28,542 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2023-08-14 12:05:28,547 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2023-08-14 12:05:30,038 INFO c.w.a.u.ConfigurationInfo: The target execution environment is: ...
2023-08-14 12:05:30,043 INFO c.w.a.u.ConfigurationInfo: The target execution site page is: ...
2023-08-14 12:05:30,048 INFO c.w.a.u.TestListener: Test result summary for MyTest {}
2023-08-14 12:05:30,083 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.J.2 sampler: Total tests executed: 0
2023-08-14 12:05:30,083 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.J.2 sampler: Total tests succeeded: 0
2023-08-14 12:05:30,083 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.J.2 sampler: Total tests failed: 0
2023-08-14 12:05:30,093 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2023-08-14 12:05:30,093 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2023-08-14 12:05:30,093 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-08-14 12:05:30,093 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Given you're "getting good help" you're supposed to [react accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
2. Given you "still cannot run the test" you're [supposed to provide the information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can help the community to identify the reason of the problem

---

Looking at my crystal ball I can see that you either have not added [junit-jupiter-params](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params) library to your [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) or haven't restarted JMeter after that or both.

Given you have a function like this in your com.example.MyTest.java file which looks like:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"parameter1", "parameter2"})
public void testWithParameter(String parameter) {
    //whatever test code you want here
}
```

You can call it from JMeter and print the parameters to the [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) as follows:

```
import org.junit.platform.engine.TestExecutionResult
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder
import org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory
import org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.SummaryGeneratingListener

import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod

def listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener() {
    @Override
    public void executionFinished(TestIdentifier testIdentifier, TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
        def testName = testIdentifier.getDisplayName()
        def result = testExecutionResult.getStatus().toString()

        log.info('Test Case: ' + testName)
        log.info('Result: ' + result)
        log.info('------------------------------------------------------------')
    }
}

def request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
        .selectors(selectMethod(com.example.MyTest.class, 'testWithParameter', String.class))
        .build()
def launcher = LauncherFactory.create()
launcher.discover(request)
launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener)
launcher.execute(request)
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I apologize for the lack of information since it's my second question here and that's a possible reason for the not completed question. 
I tried your method and unfortunately still got failure.
The possible reason for that, I suppose, could be:
1. The test class extends from the BaseTest class
2. Test data is in a json file (initialization of the test data is done on BaseTest class level). Configuration info is also in json file, but on main level and done correctly
3. Test class calls method from the BaseTest class

Comment: When I run a simple test like you provided without any extends and calling other methods and json file, it passes